# How is the instance of the class GreedyAgent() is making use of variables without creating any?

Tags: python, class, oop

Here class instance is using variables like **q_values, arm_count, last_action** which are not defined in the class GreedAgent. How is it using the variables?

```
class GreedyAgent(main_agent.Agent):
    def agent_step(self, reward, observation):
        self.arm_count[self.last_action] += 1
        self.q_values[self.last_action] += (reward - self.q_values[self.last_action]) /self.arm_count[self.last_action]
        current_action = argmax(self.q_values)
        self.last_action = current_action
        return current_action

greedy_agent = GreedyAgent()
greedy_agent.q_values = [0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0]
greedy_agent.arm_count = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
greedy_agent.last_action = 1
```

Comment: Perhaps they are defined in one of `GreedyAgent`'s superclasses, such as `main_agent.Agent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here class `GreedyAgent` is inherited from a class `main_agent.Agent`.

It could be the case that the variables are already defined as class variables in the superclass.